# How to implement hash functions $H1 \colon \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ and $H2 \colon \mathbb{Z}_p^* \to \{0,1\}^k$?

Tags: hash, implementation

I would like to implement a hash function $H1 \colon \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ such that $p$ is a prime number and second fonction $H2 \colon \mathbb{Z}_p^* \to \{0,1\}^k$ where $k$ is a security parameter

what is the best way to implement them with **SHA 256** or another hash function?

Comment: Unless $p$ is small (e.g. limited to $2^{60}$ or so), H2 is effectively unimplementable, as it would require an impractical amount of memory to store the result

Comment: @poncho I didn't understand you

Comment: $\{ 0, 1 \}^k$ means a string of $k$ bits; if $k > 2^{64}$ then that string is >2 exabytes long.  Did you mean perhaps $(0, k)$ instead?

Comment: Sorry there are no constraints on k

Comment: Hint: first, construct from SHA-256 a family of hashes $H_{(C,k)}:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^k$ parameterized by $C$ (for $k\le256$, HMAC-SHA-256 with key C and output truncated to $k$ bits will do; above, vary the constant $C$). Then build $H_2$ as $H_{(C_2,k)}$ for some arbitrary $C_2$. And build $H_1$ as$$H_1(M)=\left(H_{(C_1,\lceil\log_2(k)+\lambda\rceil)}(M)\bmod(p-1)\right)+1$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142284/discussion-on-question-by-shxxlas-how-to-implement-hash-functions-h1-colon-0).